# Which non canon characters were made canon in Dragon Ball recently?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

So aside of Broly who appears in the new Dragon Ball movie by Toriyama, and Bardock, who apparently also appears in the movie and who was incorporated to the Dragon Ball spin off Dragon Ball minus written by Toriyama, are there other non canon characters who were made canon in Dragon Ball recently?

Comment: Side note: TV Tropes has a page on the phenomenon of non-canon characters being later imported into canon: ["Canon Immigrant"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanonImmigrant).

Comment: Could you make the scope more specific other than "recently"? After *Dragon Ball Super*? Before the new *Dragon Ball* movie? Or otherwise... make this question more general by removing "recently" (though, I'm not sure if it's not too broad)

Answer (score 1):

- It's debatable whether the end of DBZ can be considered canon. Hence, the character of Uub wouldn’t technically have been canon until the Tournament of Power arc.
- Bardock has always been canon. If it weren’t for him, Goku and Raditz wouldn’t have existed. Super Saiyan Bardock is the one who isn’t canon.
- Broly like you said, will be made canon based on the trailer for the new Dragon Ball Super movie.

Comment: To be fair, to only thing canon about Bardock is his existence. His life story can still be changed to what was shown in his standalone movie

Comment: @salalito The question specified characters. Technically, Toriyama can change the story life of any character he wishes.